# How to check values between variables?

Tags: python

Need to check values of multiple variables for sameness.

Tried checking variables in a big if statement but its very tedious and surely there is a better way to do this that I dont know.

```py
num1 = random.randint(1,10)
num2 = random.randint(1,10)
num3 = random.randint(1,10)
num4 = random.randint(1,10)

print(num1, num2, num3, num4)
```

i would like for if 2 of the variables match it prints "Good job" or if 3 match it says something else and so on.

Comment: @gmds I don't see any arrays. The bigger question is, do you have a pre defined value you need to compare all 4 vars against?

Comment: Whoops, my mind inserted a `np` before the `random`.

Comment: Put your messages inside a list and then access them through their index with your `num - 1`.

Comment: Instead of generating multiple random numbers in separate variables, can you collect them in some kind of iterable, such as a `list`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `collections` module; it has classes and methods to support such needs.

1st, make a loop -- a list comprehension, for this case -- to generate your list of random numbers.  2nd, use the `Counter` class to count your values.  Finally, use `most_common()` to sort those counts for easy analysis.

```
import random
from collections import Counter

die_ct = 4
die_size = 10

# Gather all of your random numbers into a list
roll_all = [random.randint(1, die_size) for _ in range(die_ct)]
print("Die rolls", roll_all)

# Count the quantity of each value in the list
count_all = Counter(roll_all)
print("counts", count_all)

# Sort match counts for easy checking
match_sort = count_all.most_common()
print("matches", match_sort)
```

Now, iterate through `match_sort` and check the values you got; this will let you do any evaluation from simply finding the largest amount to ranking a poker hand.

Answer (score 0):

That should do:

```
from numpy import random
num1 = random.randint(1,10)
num2 = random.randint(1,10)
num3 = random.randint(1,10)
num4 = random.randint(1,10)

res = len(set([num1, num2, num3, num4]))

out = {1: '4 equal values',2: '3 equal values',3: '2 equal values',4: 'no equal values'}

print(out[res])
```

Comment: This is incorrect.  [1, 1, 2, 2] and [1, 1, 1, 2] return the same value of `2`, which you label as 3 equal values.

Comment: To use `set` you would have to do `res = roll_all.count(max(set(roll_all), key=roll_all.count))`. Not very pretty.

Answer (score -2):

try to pass values in a set() and check set's length

because set cant contain duplicated values, the length of the set will be eq the number of different values

i.e.

```
len(set([1,2,3,1,1])) = 3,

len(set([1,1,1,1,1])) = 1
```

and so on

UPD:

if you dont need group count of the sameness, than you can use groupby in itertools over the list of numbers

something like this:

```
valdict = dict((k, len(list(g))) for k, g in groupby(sorted(numbers)))
```

Comment: This is incorrect. [1, 1, 2, 2] and [1, 1, 1, 2] return the same value of 2, which you label as 3 equal values.